GNU Make in Ubuntu giving fatal error: rpc/types.h: No such file or directory
I am trying to compile Rockstar (https://bitbucket.org/gfcstanford/rockstar/src/main/).
Compiling with make, I am getting the following error and warnings:
$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/raf/Documents/astrophysics/rockstar'
cc -m64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L -D_SVID_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -Wall -fno-math-errno -fPIC main.c rockstar.c check_syscalls.c fof.c groupies.c subhalo_metric.c potential.c nfw.c jacobi.c fun_times.c interleaving.c universe_time.c hubble.c integrate.c distance.c config_vars.c config.c bounds.c inthash.c io/read_config.c client.c server.c merger.c inet/socket.c inet/rsocket.c inet/address.c io/meta_io.c io/io_internal.c io/io_ascii.c io/stringparse.c io/io_gadget.c io/io_generic.c io/io_art.c io/io_tipsy.c io/io_bgc2.c io/io_util.c io/io_arepo.c io/io_hdf5.c -o rockstar  -lm -O3 -std=c99 -rdynamic -g
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from main.c:19:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from rockstar.c:19:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from check_syscalls.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdint.h:26,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include/stdint.h:9,
                 from fof.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from groupies.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from subhalo_metric.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from potential.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from nfw.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:27,
                 from jacobi.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from fun_times.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from interleaving.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:27,
                 from universe_time.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:27,
                 from hubble.c:2:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:27,
                 from integrate.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:27,
                 from distance.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdint.h:26,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include/stdint.h:9,
                 from config_vars.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from config.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/math.h:27,
                 from bounds.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from inthash.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/read_config.c:2:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from client.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from server.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from merger.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from inet/socket.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from inet/rsocket.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from inet/address.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:26,
                 from io/meta_io.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from io/meta_io.c:21:
io/io_tipsy.h:4:10: fatal error: rpc/types.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <rpc/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/io_internal.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/io_ascii.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/stringparse.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/io_gadget.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:26,
                 from io/io_generic.c:4:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/io_art.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/io_tipsy.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
io/io_tipsy.c:7:10: fatal error: rpc/types.h: No such file or directory
    7 | #include <rpc/types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdint.h:26,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/include/stdint.h:9,
                 from io/io_bgc2.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from io/io_util.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:196:3: warning: #warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE" [-Wcpp]
  196 | # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE"
      |   ^~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [Makefile:38: reg] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/raf/Documents/astrophysics/rockstar'
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2

The GNU make I am using in Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS:
$ make -version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

How can I to fix the issues?

This has nothing to do with make.  You're missing a header file, so figure out what package provides that header and insatll it.

It compiles once you do these changes.
Make sure you've installed tirpc:
sudo apt install libtirpc-dev # execute this from a terminal 

Then edit the Makefile with the following changes:

On line 1 add the following to CFLAGS:
-I/usr/include/tirpc


On line 3 add the following to OFLAGS:
-ltirpc



Please note I have zero knowledge of this code however I googled your question. On my Ubuntu 24.04 laptop I did a git clone of the code and made those edits to the Makefile as per the link above.
Afterwards to compile just issue:
make


Sorry, I am confused. Can you please specify the lines where I should make these changes or share the fully modified Makefile?

Thank you, regarding the warning: # warning "_BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE are deprecated, use _DEFAULT_SOURCE", should I simply replace both _BSD_SOURCE and _SVID_SOURCE with _DEFAULT_SOURCE?

depends ... if you own that code yes try to fix it with suggested edits  ... however deprecated is just a notice so the code will work as it says on the tin until sometime later when the owners of the deprecated code transition it into a fatal change ... if you are creating a static binary you will be OK ignoring that notice as your binary will not be pulling in outside libraries at execution time only during compile time
